# Odata receiving "The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, odata

I'm kind of new on Odata and Web Api. I get this error from my get request in Fiddler:

The controller for path '/odata/Unit' was not found or does not implement IController

```
public class UnitController : EntitySetController<Unit, Guid>
{
    public DEVEntities _Context { get; set; }

    public UnitController()
    {
        this._Context = new DEVEntities();
    }

    public override IQueryable<Unit> Get()
    {
        return _Context.UnitSet;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My WebApiConfig.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Unit>("Units");
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

I can get http://server/odata/$metadata with no problems but when I try:

but when I try http://server/odata/Unit I get:

[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/odata/Unit&#39; was not found or does  not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Please help I'm getting very frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer and I have to change ODataModelBuilder to the ODataConventionModelBuilder.

That solved the issue.

And one should change "Units" to "Unit" to map to the correct controller.

Answer (score 0):

I thought your UnitController or EntitySetController didn't inherit ApiController